# startLockTask() not working android

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to pin an activity using startActivity() on android in my onCreate method of my main activity.  However it doesn't seem to recognise the method.  I set my target **sdk to 5.0** but it still doesn't recognise it.

Here is the error that I get:

The method `startLockTask()` is undefined for the type MainActivity

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to set the Project Build Target to 5.0 under properties in Eclipse.  I hope this helps other people out.